# Double-hashtags followed by asterisk syntax

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to figure out a script that I need to rewrite.

and there is the following syntax

```
temp_var=${variable##* -p}
```

I look it up but didn't find anything like this....

Can you tell me what the Double-hashtags followed by asterisk syntax mean?

Comment: First hit in GNU bash's manpage if you search `##`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [bash parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

> **`${var##Pattern}`** Remove from `$var` the longest part of `$Pattern` that matches the front end of `$var`.

Example:

```
$ var=asssssssdf
$ echo ${var##a*s}
df
```